# Problems initializing global variables

Tags: c++, initialization, global

**HEADER FILE**

```
#ifndef H_MODEL_UTIL
#define H_MODEL_UTIL

#include "Mesh.h"

Mesh *kingHigh;

void InitModel();

#endif
```

**SOURCE FILE**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ResourceLoader.h"
#include "ModelUtil.h"

void InitModel()
{
    ::kingHigh  = new Mesh();
}
```

Compiler output:

```
1>Game.obj : error LNK2005: "class Mesh * kingHigh" (?kingHigh@@3PAVMesh@@A) already defined in Cube.obj

1>ModelUtil.obj : error LNK2005: "class Mesh * kingHigh" (?kingHigh@@3PAVMesh@@A) already defined in Cube.obj

1>C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\C++ Learning\Extra\Rubiks Chess\Debug\Rubiks Chess.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I am trying to initialize a global variable but I keep getting this error. Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not in the way you init mesh , it's in your declaration. your header file should declare mesh as external

```
 extern Mesh *kingHigh;
```

and declare mesh in your .cpp file

```
 Mesh *kingHigh;
```

it must prevent the multiple definition you got !

Answer (score 1):

You have redefined Mesh in InitModel.kinghigh is global so its already defined.just delete the content of InitModel.and also you can write `extern Mesh *kinghigh`